# Titling package

Tags: titles, titling

In the footer of a page, *footnotes* and *thanks* are not correctly aligned. How to get the expected alignment?

---

In the following example, the commands `\thanks{}` are typeset using numbers, as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\thanksmarkseries{arabic}
\continuousmarks

\author{A. U. Thor\thanks{Is grateful\dots}}
\title{Nice paper\thanks{Indeed\dots}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This paper deals with\footnote{See also\dots}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align them by specifying the `\thanksmarkwidth` to be same as the indent in front of foot note.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\thanksmarkseries{arabic}
\continuousmarks
\setlength{\thanksmarkwidth}{\parindent}     %%% <--- here
\author{A. U. Thor\thanks{Is grateful\dots}}
\title{Nice paper\thanks{Indeed\dots}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This paper deals with\footnote{See also\dots}
\end{document}
```

[image]